# Installing mp4 mod for nginx

Tags: nginx

I already have nginx installed on my server but I wanted to add the mp4 located at http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Nginx-Version2. If run these commands in my nginx directory

```
./configure --add-module=$HOME/nginx_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.7 --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --with-debug
make
sudo make install
```

will my old configurations and files get overwritten? If so, how can I do this so everything is the same as before but with the mod added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
savetherbtz@PH34R:~$ nginx -V
nginx: nginx version: nginx/1.0.5
nginx: TLS SNI support enabled
nginx: configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.0.5/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.0.5/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
```

PS. Recent versions of nginx have [ngx_http_mp4_module](http://www.nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html)

Comment: /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/0.8.54
built by gcc 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13) (GCC)
configure arguments: --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module --with-http_flv_module

Comment: `./configure` it with same options and run `make install`. Backups may be useful anyway in case something goes wrong

Comment: Is --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin supposed to point to my sbin directory or my actual nginx binary?

Comment: it depends on what you want to archive - overwrite your existing installation of nginx or install another one.